# Autofill fields within iframe in another domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to autofill in some fields on the site with the extension.The problem is that these fields are in iframe of another domain and this iframe is inside another iframe with src="about:blank". I tried to include "all_frames" true in the manifest but it seems that the code from content.js is not executed at all in any of these iframes. At the same time I have some extensions that are able to autofill fields even inside iframe with src of another domain, therefore it is possible. What am I missing?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Add `"match_about_blank": true` too.

Comment: It's always better to add your code snippet with the question, highlighting the approach you have taken.